# I'm trying to make Higher or Lower game, how can I make it so when the user guesses right the second driver goes where the first driver was in round 2

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm making higher or Lower game.
-How can I make it so when the user guesses right the second driver goes where the first driver was in round 2. Like this:
Round 1:
Higher or Lower wins:
Hamilton
vs
Alonso
(lets say that the user guesses lower, which is right because Alonso has lower wins than Hamilton), then in round 2 it should look like this:
Round 2:
Higher or Lower wins:
Alonso
vs
Verstappen
(lets say that the user guesses higher, which is right because Verstappen has higher wins than Alonso), then in round 3 it should look like this:
Round 3:
Higher or Lower wins:
Verstappen
vs
Rosberg
(lets say that the user guesses lower, which is right because Rosberg has lower wins than Verstappen), and so on and so on.

Another question, it seems like the question or what the user is guessing doesn't appear. Also how can I hide the drivers stats so when the driver guesses then the stats are shown.

```js
// Define F1 driver data
const f1Drivers = [
{ name: 'Lewis Hamilton', wins: 103, podiums: 191, points: 4425.5 },
{ name: 'Michael Schumacher', wins: 91, podiums: 155, points: 1566 },
{ name: 'Sebastian Vettel', wins: 53, podiums: 122, points: 3098 },
{ name: 'Alain Prost', wins: 51, podiums: 106, points: 798.5 },
{ name: 'Ayrton Senna', wins: 41, podiums: 80, points: 614 },
{ name: 'Nigel Mansell', wins: 31, podiums: 59, points: 482 },
{ name: 'Jim Clark', wins: 25, podiums: 32, points: 274.5 },
{ name: 'Juan Manuel Fangio', wins: 24, podiums: 35, points: 277.64 },
{ name: 'Niki Lauda', wins: 25, podiums: 54, points: 420.5 },
{ name: 'Jack Brabham', wins: 14, podiums: 31, points: 261 },
{ name: 'Fernando Alonso', wins: 32, podiums: 100, points: 2091 },
{ name: 'Max Verstappen', wins: 36, podiums: 79, points: 2055.5 },
{ name: 'Nico Rosberg', wins: 23, podiums: 57, points: 1594.5 },
{ name: 'Kimi Raikkonen', wins: 21, podiums: 103, points: 1873 },
{ name: 'Mika Hakkinen', wins: 20, podiums: 51, points: 420 },
{ name: 'Jenson Button', wins: 15, podiums: 50, points: 1235 },
{ name: 'Jackie Stewart', wins: 27, podiums: 43, points: 359 },
{ name: 'Damon Hill', wins: 22, podiums: 42, points: 360 },
{ name: 'Felipe Massa', wins: 11, podiums: 41, points: 1167 },
{ name: 'Valtteri Bottas', wins: 10, podiums: 67, points: 1791 },
{ name: 'Mark Webber', wins: 9, podiums: 50, points: 1235 },
{ name: 'Daniel Ricciardo', wins: 8, podiums: 32, points: 1311 },
];

// Get HTML elements
const difficultySelect = document.getElementById('difficulty-select');
const startGameButton = document.querySelector('button');
const gameContainer = document.getElementById('game-container');
const higherButton = document.getElementById('higher-button');
const lowerButton = document.getElementById('lower-button');
const resultContainer = document.getElementById('result-container');
const playAgainButton = document.getElementById('play-again-button');
const frontImage = document.getElementById('bikar');


let currentDriverIndex;
let previousDriverIndex;
let currentDifficulty;
let score;


// Add event listener to the "Start Game" button
startGameButton.addEventListener('click', startGame);

function startGame() {
    // Get a reference to the front image element and hide it
    const frontImage = document.getElementById('bikar');
    frontImage.style.display = 'none';

    // Show the type of data to be guessed by the user
    const dataTypeElement = document.getElementById('data-type');
    if (currentDifficulty === 'easy') {
    dataTypeElement.textContent = 'Guess the driver with more wins';
  } else if (currentDifficulty === 'normal') {
    dataTypeElement.textContent = 'Guess the driver with more podiums';
  } else if (currentDifficulty === 'hard') {
    dataTypeElement.textContent = 'Guess the driver with more points';
  }
    
    higherButton.addEventListener('click', onHigherButtonClicked);
    lowerButton.addEventListener('click', onLowerButtonClicked);

    currentDifficulty = difficultySelect.value;
    score = 0;
  
    // Hide the result container and play again button
    resultContainer.textContent = '';
    playAgainButton.style.display = 'none';
  
    // Show the first driver
    showNextDriver();
}


function onHigherButtonClicked() {
    checkAnswer('higher');
}
  
function onLowerButtonClicked() {
    checkAnswer('lower');
}

let lastDriverIndex;
function showNextDriver() {
    // Clear the previous driver's data
    gameContainer.innerHTML = '';
  
    // Pick two random drivers from the list
    currentDriverIndex = getRandomDriverIndex();
    previousDriverIndex = getRandomDriverIndex(currentDriverIndex);
  
    // Create and append elements to display the two drivers and their data
    const currentDriverElement = document.createElement('div');
    const previousDriverElement = document.createElement('div');
    const currentDriverDataElement = document.createElement('ul');
    const previousDriverDataElement = document.createElement('ul');
    const vsElement = document.createElement('div');

    currentDriverElement.classList.add('driver');
    previousDriverElement.classList.add('driver');
    vsElement.textContent = "Vs";
    
  
    currentDriverElement.innerHTML = `
      <h2>${f1Drivers[currentDriverIndex].name}</h2>
      <img src="driver-images/${f1Drivers[currentDriverIndex].name.toLowerCase().replace(' ', '-')}.jpg" alt="${f1Drivers[currentDriverIndex].name}">
    `;
    previousDriverElement.innerHTML = `
      <h2>${f1Drivers[previousDriverIndex].name}</h2>
      <img src="driver-images/${f1Drivers[previousDriverIndex].name.toLowerCase().replace(' ', '-')}.jpg" alt="${f1Drivers[previousDriverIndex].name}">
    `;
  
    if (currentDifficulty === 'easy') {
      currentDriverDataElement.innerHTML = `
        <li>Wins: ${f1Drivers[currentDriverIndex].wins}</li>
      `;
      previousDriverDataElement.innerHTML = `
        <li>Wins: ${f1Drivers[previousDriverIndex].wins}</li>
      `;
    } else if (currentDifficulty === 'normal') {
      currentDriverDataElement.innerHTML = `
        <li>Podiums: ${f1Drivers[currentDriverIndex].podiums}</li>
      `;
      previousDriverDataElement.innerHTML = `
        <li>Podiums: ${f1Drivers[previousDriverIndex].podiums}</li>
      `;
    } else if (currentDifficulty === 'hard') {
      currentDriverDataElement.innerHTML = `
        <li>Points: ${f1Drivers[currentDriverIndex].points}</li>
      `;
      previousDriverDataElement.innerHTML = `
        <li>Points: ${f1Drivers[previousDriverIndex].points}</li>
      `;
    }
  
    currentDriverElement.appendChild(currentDriverDataElement);
    previousDriverElement.appendChild(previousDriverDataElement);
    gameContainer.appendChild(currentDriverElement);
    gameContainer.appendChild(vsElement);
    gameContainer.appendChild(previousDriverElement);
  
    // Show the "Higher or Lower" buttons
    const buttonContainer = document.getElementById('button-container');
    buttonContainer.style.display = 'block';
}
  
function getRandomDriverIndex(excludeIndex) {
    let index;
    do {
      index = Math.floor(Math.random() * f1Drivers.length);
    } while (index === excludeIndex);
    return index;
}


function checkAnswer(guess) {
    const previousDriver = f1Drivers[previousDriverIndex];
    const currentDriver = f1Drivers[currentDriverIndex];
    let previousData, currentData;
    if (currentDifficulty === 'easy') {
      previousData = previousDriver.wins;
      currentData = currentDriver.wins;
    } else if (currentDifficulty === 'normal') {
      previousData = previousDriver.podiums;
      currentData = currentDriver.podiums;
    } else if (currentDifficulty === 'hard') {
      previousData = previousDriver.points;
      currentData = currentDriver.points;
    }
  
    const answerIsCorrect =
      (guess === 'higher' && currentData < previousData) ||
      (guess === 'lower' && currentData > previousData);
      
  
    if (answerIsCorrect) {
      score++;
      showNextDriver();
    } else {
      endGame();
    }
}


function endGame() {
  // Remove event listeners from the buttons
  higherButton.removeEventListener('click', onHigherButtonClicked);
  lowerButton.removeEventListener('click', onLowerButtonClicked);

  let message = "";
  if (score <= 1) {
    message = `That's a poor score, you should learn more about F1.`;
  } else if (score <= 4) {
    message = `That's okay, not good.`;
  } else if (score <= 10) {
    message = `You are good!!`;
  } else {
```

```css
/* Style the header */
header {
    background-color: #333;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    }
    
    /* Style the game container */
    #game-container {
    margin: 20px;
    font-size: 24px;
    text-align: center;
    }
    
    /* Style the button container */
    #button-container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    }
    
    /* Style the result container */
    #result-container {
    font-size: 24px;
    text-align: center;
    }
    
    /* Style the footer */
    footer {
    background-color: #333;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    }
    
    /* Style the "Higher" and "Lower" buttons */
    button {
    font-size: 24px;
    margin: 0 10px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    /* Style the selected difficulty option */
    #difficulty option:checked {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Higher or Lower F1 Game</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="higher_or_lower.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <h1>Higher or Lower F1 Game</h1>
      <label for="difficulty-select">Choose difficulty level:</label>
      <select id="difficulty-select">
        <option value="easy">Easy</option>
        <option value="normal">Normal</option>
        <option value="hard">Hard</option>
      </select>
      <button id="start-game-button">Start Game</button>
    </header>
    <img id="bikar" src="bikar.png" style="width:1500px;height:1500px;">
    <main>
      <div id="game-container">
      <div id="data-type"></div>
        <!-- Display F1 driver data here -->
      </div>
      <div id="button-container" style="display: none;">
        <button id="higher-button">Higher</button>
        <button id="lower-button">Lower</button>
      </div>
      <div id="result-container">
        <!-- Display game result here -->
      </div>
      <button id="play-again-button" style="display:none">Play Again</button>
    </main>
    <footer>
      <p>Created by xxx</p>
    </footer>
    <script src="higher_or_lower.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to assign your currentDriver as previousDriver when users guess is correct.

```
if (answerIsCorrect) {
    score++;
    currentDriverIndex = previousDriverIndex;
    previousDriverIndex = null;
    showNextDriver();
  }
```

and when you assign them initially just add check if they are null like this

```
// Pick two random drivers from the list
  if (!currentDriverIndex) {
    currentDriverIndex = getRandomDriverIndex();
  }

  if (!previousDriverIndex) {
    previousDriverIndex = getRandomDriverIndex(currentDriverIndex);
  }
```

Please check below.

```js
// Define F1 driver data
const f1Drivers = [
{
    name: 'Lewis Hamilton',
    wins: 103,
    podiums: 191,
    points: 4425.5
  },
  {
    name: 'Michael Schumacher',
    wins: 91,
    podiums: 155,
    points: 1566
  },
  {
    name: 'Sebastian Vettel',
    wins: 53,
    podiums: 122,
    points: 3098
  },
  {
    name: 'Alain Prost',
    wins: 51,
    podiums: 106,
    points: 798.5
  },
  {
    name: 'Ayrton Senna',
    wins: 41,
    podiums: 80,
    points: 614
  },
  {
    name: 'Nigel Mansell',
    wins: 31,
    podiums: 59,
    points: 482
  },
  {
    name: 'Jim Clark',
    wins: 25,
    podiums: 32,
    points: 274.5
  },
  {
    name: 'Juan Manuel Fangio',
    wins: 24,
    podiums: 35,
    points: 277.64
  },
  {
    name: 'Niki Lauda',
    wins: 25,
    podiums: 54,
    points: 420.5
  },
  {
    name: 'Jack Brabham',
    wins: 14,
    podiums: 31,
    points: 261
  },
  {
    name: 'Fernando Alonso',
    wins: 32,
    podiums: 100,
    points: 2091
  },
  {
    name: 'Max Verstappen',
    wins: 36,
    podiums: 79,
    points: 2055.5
  },
  {
    name: 'Nico Rosberg',
    wins: 23,
    podiums: 57,
    points: 1594.5
  },
  {
    name: 'Kimi Raikkonen',
    wins: 21,
    podiums: 103,
    points: 1873
  },
  {
    name: 'Mika Hakkinen',
    wins: 20,
    podiums: 51,
    points: 420
  },
  {
    name: 'Jenson Button',
    wins: 15,
    podiums: 50,
    points: 1235
  },
  {
    name: 'Jackie Stewart',
    wins: 27,
    podiums: 43,
    points: 359
  },
  {
    name: 'Damon Hill',
    wins: 22,
    podiums: 42,
    points: 360
  },
  {
    name: 'Felipe Massa',
    wins: 11,
    podiums: 41,
    points: 1167
  },
  {
    name: 'Valtteri Bottas',
    wins: 10,
    podiums: 67,
    points: 1791
  },
  {
    name: 'Mark Webber',
    wins: 9,
    podiums: 50,
    points: 1235
  },
  {
    name: 'Daniel Ricciardo',
    wins: 8,
    podiums: 32,
    points: 1311
  },
];

// Get HTML elements
const difficultySelect = document.getElementById('difficulty-select');
const startGameButton = document.querySelector('button');
const gameContainer = document.getElementById('game-container');
const higherButton = document.getElementById('higher-button');
const lowerButton = document.getElementById('lower-button');
const resultContainer = document.getElementById('result-container');
const playAgainButton = document.getElementById('play-again-button');
const frontImage = document.getElementById('bikar');


let currentDriverIndex;
let previousDriverIndex;
let currentDifficulty;
let score;


// Add event listener to the "Start Game" button
startGameButton.addEventListener('click', startGame);

function startGame() {
  // Get a reference to the front image element and hide it
  frontImage.style.display = 'none';

  higherButton.addEventListener('click', onHigherButtonClicked);
  lowerButton.addEventListener('click', onLowerButtonClicked);

  currentDifficulty = difficultySelect.value;
  score = 0;

  // Hide the result container and play again button
  resultContainer.textContent = '';
  playAgainButton.style.display = 'none';

  // Show the first driver
  showNextDriver();
}


function onHigherButtonClicked() {
  checkAnswer('higher');
}

function onLowerButtonClicked() {
  checkAnswer('lower');
}

let lastDriverIndex;

function showNextDriver() {
  // Clear the previous driver's data
  gameContainer.innerHTML = '';

  // Pick two random drivers from the list
  if (!currentDriverIndex) {
    currentDriverIndex = getRandomDriverIndex();
  }

  if (!previousDriverIndex) {
    previousDriverIndex = getRandomDriverIndex(currentDriverIndex);
  }

  // Create and append elements to display the two drivers and their data
  const currentDriverElement = document.createElement('div');
  const previousDriverElement = document.createElement('div');
  const currentDriverDataElement = document.createElement('ul');
  const previousDriverDataElement = document.createElement('ul');
  const vsElement = document.createElement('div');

  currentDriverElement.classList.add('driver');
  previousDriverElement.classList.add('driver');
  vsElement.textContent = "Vs";

  currentDriverElement.innerHTML = `
      <h2>${f1Drivers[currentDriverIndex].name}</h2>
      <img src="driver-images/${f1Drivers[currentDriverIndex].name.toLowerCase().replace(' ', '-')}.jpg" alt="${f1Drivers[currentDriverIndex].name}">
    `;
  previousDriverElement.innerHTML = `
      <h2>${f1Drivers[previousDriverIndex].name}</h2>
      <img src="driver-images/${f1Drivers[previousDriverIndex].name.toLowerCase().replace(' ', '-')}.jpg" alt="${f1Drivers[previousDriverIndex].name}">
    `;

  if (currentDifficulty === 'easy') {
    currentDriverDataElement.innerHTML = `
        <li>Wins: ${f1Drivers[currentDriverIndex].wins}</li>
      `;
    previousDriverDataElement.innerHTML = `
        <li>Wins: ${f1Drivers[previousDriverIndex].wins}</li>
      `;
  } else if (currentDifficulty === 'normal') {
    currentDriverDataElement.innerHTML = `
        <li>Podiums: ${f1Drivers[currentDriverIndex].podiums}</li>
      `;
    previousDriverDataElement.innerHTML = `
        <li>Podiums: ${f1Drivers[previousDriverIndex].podiums}</li>
      `;
  } else if (currentDifficulty === 'hard') {
    currentDriverDataElement.innerHTML = `
        <li>Points: ${f1Drivers[currentDriverIndex].points}</li>
      `;
    previousDriverDataElement.innerHTML = `
        <li>Points: ${f1Drivers[previousDriverIndex].points}</li>
      `;
  }

  currentDriverElement.appendChild(currentDriverDataElement);
  previousDriverElement.appendChild(previousDriverDataElement);
  gameContainer.appendChild(currentDriverElement);
  gameContainer.appendChild(vsElement);
  gameContainer.appendChild(previousDriverElement);

  // Show the "Higher or Lower" buttons
  const buttonContainer = document.getElementById('button-container');
  buttonContainer.style.display = 'block';
}

function getRandomDriverIndex(excludeIndex) {
  let index;
  do {
    index = Math.floor(Math.random() * f1Drivers.length);
  } while (index === excludeIndex);
  return index;
}


function checkAnswer(guess) {
  const previousDriver = f1Drivers[previousDriverIndex];
  const currentDriver = f1Drivers[currentDriverIndex];
  let previousData, currentData;
  if (currentDifficulty === 'easy') {
    previousData = previousDriver.wins;
    currentData = currentDriver.wins;
  } else if (currentDifficulty === 'normal') {
    previousData = previousDriver.podiums;
    currentData = currentDriver.podiums;
  } else if (currentDifficulty === 'hard') {
    previousData = previousDriver.points;
    currentData = currentDriver.points;
  }

  const answerIsCorrect =
    (guess === 'higher' && currentData < previousData) ||
    (guess === 'lower' && currentData > previousData);


  if (answerIsCorrect) {
    score++;
    currentDriverIndex = previousDriverIndex;
    previousDriverIndex = null;
    showNextDriver();
  } else {
    endGame();
  }
}


function endGame() {
  // Remove event listeners from the buttons
  higherButton.removeEventListener('click', onHigherButtonClicked);
  lowerButton.removeEventListener('click', onLowerButtonClicked);

  let message = "";
  if (score <= 1) {
    message = `That's a poor score, you should learn more about F1.`;
  } else if (score <= 4) {
    message = `That's okay, not good.`;
  } else if (score <= 10) {
    message = `You are good!!`;
  } else {
    message = `WOW!! Touch grass!!`;
  }

  // Display the user's score and message
  resultContainer.textContent = `Game over! You got ${score} correct. ${message}`;
  playAgainButton.style.display = 'block';
  playAgainButton.addEventListener('click', startGame);
}
```

```css
/* Style the header */
header {
    background-color: #333;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    }
    
    /* Style the game container */
    #game-container {
    margin: 20px;
    font-size: 24px;
    text-align: center;
    }
    
    /* Style the button container */
    #button-container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    }
    
    /* Style the result container */
    #result-container {
    font-size: 24px;
    text-align: center;
    }
    
    /* Style the footer */
    footer {
    background-color: #333;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    }
    
    /* Style the "Higher" and "Lower" buttons */
    button {
    font-size: 24px;
    margin: 0 10px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    /* Style the selected difficulty option */
    #difficulty option:checked {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Higher or Lower F1 Game</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <h1>Higher or Lower F1 Game</h1>
      <label for="difficulty-select">Choose difficulty level:</label>
      <select id="difficulty-select">
        <option value="easy">Easy</option>
        <option value="normal">Normal</option>
        <option value="hard">Hard</option>
      </select>
      <button id="start-game-button">Start Game</button>
    </header>
    <img id="bikar" src="bikar.png" alt="biker" style="width:1500px;height:1500px;">
    <main>
      <div id="game-container">
      <div id="data-type"></div>
        <!-- Display F1 driver data here -->
      </div>
      <div id="button-container" style="display: none;">
        <button id="higher-button">Higher</button>
        <button id="lower-button">Lower</button>
      </div>
      <div id="result-container">
        <!-- Display game result here -->
      </div>
      <button id="play-again-button" style="display:none">Play Again</button>
    </main>
    <footer>
      <p>Created by xxx</p>
    </footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: Ok Thanks, but nothing happens when the game happens in these codes.

Comment: What error do you see? Can you please check now. I have updated answer.

Comment: I don't see no errors but, when I run this now, there is no question or 'Guess which driver has more (attribute)' depending on the difficulty. The stats(attribute) are not supposed to be shown when the game starts only after the user guesses. I think that is all :)

Comment: I do see the question when i click on start game. stats/score is only showing after game is end. And 'Guess which driver...' line was not working in your initial code as well. It was showing error. Added it back. Here is working version. https://jsfiddle.net/codething/78jqns4f/22/

Comment: Ok on the link though I cant see no higher or lower buttons when the game is started and the drivers stats are supposed to be shown only when the user guesses. Maybe it has something to do with my browser, idk.

Comment: @John Check attached image. What do you mean by stats. Are you referring to final score?

Comment: Im sorry I wasn’t clear enough, by stats I mean their win, podiums, points. Depending on the difficulty. So the user has to read the question and guess.

Comment: I see. I guess you can do that easily. It's not that hard. You just have to hide that ul element. and show it when any of the button is clicked.

Comment: Yeah ur right….

Comment: Thanks again, but somehow there seems to be a bug in this. Always when Hamilton appears to be guessed if he has higher or lower than the previous driver he doesn't appear in the next round. Understand?